# Llinking css from base folder to jekyll site

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to deploy a jekyll site for my personal website, under a "blog" folder. When I try to link a css to default.html Jekyll is looking for css file under blog/css folder, however my css files are located at blog/../css i.e on my main "website" folder which contains, "blog" folder, "css" folder etc. Is there a way I can link my jekyll site to the css files on the base folder without having to move the config.yml file. I tried changing the baseurl to ../blog but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is to symlink `blog/../css` to `blog/css`

Jekyll will pull the css files through the symlink when generating the site.

*One thing to note: when doing `jekyll serve`, vanilla Jekyll will **not** regenerate based on changes to symlinked files. (There is a plugin to do this, but for a personal site, that's overkill: just stop `jekyll serve` and restart)*

Depending on the theme, you can also modify the header (typically `_includes/head.html`) to have your manually specified css file.

Answer (score 0):

If your ***css*** are at the root of your repository, from ***blog*** folder, you just have to link with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```